# Pasue Console Application At End

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I want to know how it is possible to pause a console application at end and by pressing enter, it ends in assembely. here is a peice of code which shows "hello world" on screen, but it will close immediatly. So how to pause program at end?

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc

.data
sConsoleTitle  db "Console Application",0
sWriteText  db "Hello World",0
.code

Main PROC
    LOCAL hStdout :DWORD
    invoke SetConsoleTitleA, offset sConsoleTitle

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov hStdout,EAX

    invoke WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset sWriteText, 16d, 0, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

Main ENDP
end Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already working with a console (I see `stdout` and `WriteConsole`) I'm going to suggest that you work with a proper console:

- `cmd.exe`. Can simply be run off Start -> Run and is included with every modern Windows. Can be modified to use different fonts, resized, etc.
- [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/powershell/). Most people like it. I don't.
- A terminal program like [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/). Tabs, translucency and Linux-like mouse behavior are great to have.

Clicking an .exe to run it is great, but what happens if you want to supply it input? Command line parameters? What if you want to redirect stdin/stdout? What if you want to pipe a file to it, or it to another program, like grep? What if you wanted to run your program non-interactively, e.g. from a script?

It's one of *Windows's* shortcomings to be unable to work with console programs easily. Please do not compensate for this in your code and upset everyone who's found a way to do it.

Another option is creating a batch file that calls your executable and then does `pause`.

Comment: You mean besides what I wrote about pausing for user non-input? Nothing, I guess. Though, what does this mean? "ReadConsole fails if used with a standard handle that has been redirected to be something other than a console handle."

Comment: To comment on your answer, `cmd` and `Powershell` both use the same Windows console host, so they don't have any different features (font, resizing...) but `Powershell` is, of course, a different shell.